# We can post two answers for double the rep?

Tags: discussion

I just came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293167/r-fitting-text-on-abline#23296226) in which seven minutes elapsed between the time the answerer made his/her first answer, and the time an exact duplicate of that answer appeared.

How and why is that allowed to happen?

[image]

Comment: Didn't see what you mean, or it get fixed already..

Comment: @Bolu the author has deleted one of the answers so it wouldn't be visible to <10k users

Comment: Even if it was intentional, I doubt it would get anyone double the rep. Users blindly upvote, but I don't think they're so blind that they upvote the exact same content from the same user twice.

Comment: The "double the rep" was just a hook to get people in here. :)

Comment: See also: [Two Answers, One Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28471/two-answers-one-question)

Comment: See also: [Can a single user post two answers for one question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165831/can-a-single-user-post-two-answers-for-one-question)

Comment: See also: [What is the official etiquette on answering a question twice?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice)

Comment: (Not to mention several questions closed as duplicates of the above.)

Comment: The double the rep trick and the dupes scored you a -1 from my side.

Comment: You can even post 3 answers for triple the rep! ...Of course, this works better if [the first two are wrong](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180524/please-stop-sending-me-emails-when-my-bounty-is-going-to-expire-soon).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, of course, submit multiple answers, because a question may have multiple possible solutions. Better to have each solution in its own answer so each can be independently voted on.

But what you've got there is a duplicate answer, probably due to some transient network issue. I doubt it was intentional. (Maybe the author thought they were editing and didn't realize they were creating a new answer.)

I think the thing to do is flag it for Moderator attention using the "Other" option and explain it's a duplicate answer. (Make it easy on the Mods; provide a link to the answer of which it's a duplicate.)

Alternatively (or additionally) you could leave a comment on one of the answers to alert the author that there's a duplicate. One would hope that he/she would then remove the duplicate answer on his/her own.

Comment: Unless you, for whatever reason, strongly believe it wasn't an accident (such as history of the author) I would recommend commenting to the person *first*. No need to involve the mods if it can be handled through comments.

Comment: Interesting.  I just put all the solutions I can think of into one complete answer.

Comment: @RichardScriven There's nothing wrong with putting multiple solutions into multiple answers.  If the solutions are completely distinct, multiple answers makes them more readable.

Comment: When I know multiple solutions to the same problem, I usually also have some ideas on criteria for choosing between them. That is usually easier to express in one answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing to stop a person from posting multiple answers, AFAIK. But, to answer your question, no that is not alright. The main focus of the network isn't to farm rep but to build a good Q/A DB. So, double-posting simply for rep would clutter the site and go against its purpose.

We do have mechanisms such as flags, comments, and such so when this happens you should first:

1. Comment to the OP to get a dialog going to remove one post
2. If they don't remove then flag as an exact duplicate of their other answer

The author has since deleted one of the answers. Most likely, it was a mistake in not understanding how to edit or just an accident.

Comment: Well, there is "something" to stop someone from posting multiple answers. After you've already answered a question you need to click a button and dismiss an alert in order to post another answer.

Comment: @user3524344 but how does that stop someone from posting another?

Comment: It doesn't stop them per se, but if someone wasn't intending to post another answer they would stop themselves.

Comment: I've never tried to post more than one answer, that I recall, so I don't know about the popup. But, my statement and answer still stand, "There's nothing to stop a person from posting multiple answers,"

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that this can easily happen by accident. So I wouldn't assume that anybody double posted with bad intentions.

In my case, I had finished an answer, clicked Post Your Answer, and went away from the computer. When I got back, it was still sitting there in the answer edit mode, with the Post Your Answer button enabled. I figured that the submission had failed, which has been common for me the last few days ([Temporarily lost login while being active](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267977/temporarily-lost-login-while-being-active)). So I clicked Post Your Answer again, it brought me to the screen where I had to verify that I was human, and then showed me the question page with my answer in place. TWICE!

The answer had actually been submitted successfully the first time. I just didn't get any feedback, and it left me with the answer still showing in edit mode, and the Post button active.