# Duplicate answer

Tags: bug, duplicate-answers

I was editing my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813306/setting-link-font-with-css), when I got a popup that another answer was posted. After I saved my changes, it turned out that the other answer was a duplicate of my own answer.

I couldn't find much information about this phenomenon here, apart from [We can post two answers for double the rep?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252176/we-can-post-two-answers-for-double-the-rep), which accidentally seems to be about the same issue.

I don't think I did anything weird. Is this a bug?

No harm done, by the way, I just removed the duplicate.

Comment: Let's not close this since this time it's actually a bug report and ... yeah, this is kinda weird.

Comment: @AnnaLear [another possible occurrence here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891685/mockito-define-mock-behaviour)

Comment: Bumping because I got the same issue again, now for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28571336/browser-support-for-numeric-font-weight/28571403#28571403). Recap: My first attempt to post was too short (less than 30 chars, excluding a link). I added extra text and posted. I then removed a comment I posted before (to the question). After that, I edited the answer to add another paragraph, and while doing that, I got the "other answer" popup, which turned out to be the previous version of my answer again.

Comment: By the way, it was again a question related to CSS fonts, so maybe therein lies the issue. ;-)

Comment: [Another occurrence here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28776769/190597).

Comment: [another occurence](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293735/57475)

Comment: It happened to me again [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559517/setting-margins-from-browser-window/30559569#30559569). This time I was copy-pasting a chunk of code and hacking in one of the runnable snippets, although it may be that I (again) made two edits in quick succession...

Comment: It happened to me today https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58590256/capture-date-after-regex-using-awk/58591246#58591246, I apologize, but I don't know how I managed to duplicate the answer. How can I delete it? I've tried to flag it, but it was declined. What can I do?