# Should I flag my own double-posted answer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-answers

I posted an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29498771/4669462), and for some reason I ended up posting it twice. I might have double-clicked 'Post your answer', but I'm not sure what happened really.

**Should I flag my own duplicate answer** so a moderator can delete it or should I just ignore it? I know users with 10k+ reputation can view deleted content and it can get noisy. (Note: This is the second time I made this mistake.)

Also, is there a feature-request to delete one of your answers if you posted it multiple times on the same question?

Comment: trigger happy...?

Comment: @rene Hahah I'm not sure why it happens in all honesty

Comment: not exactly a duplicate, but some background on the problem: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265986/duplicate-answer

Comment: @Tanner So its a common bug then, I'm guessing?

Comment: @logic it's not that common, but there have been occurrences. As far as I know, they've not found the cause yet. If you are able to do it again, you may want to post against that question to add any relevant information that might help to find the cause. Perhaps just add a comment, linking to your 2 occurrences. like others have done.

Comment: @Tanner Ok :) will do

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just ignore it.

You did the right thing by deleting the duplicate. All a moderator would be able to do is delete it anyway. You've already deleted it, so no need to flag a moderator.

P.S. Most of us 10k+ users have probably managed to do something similar, we won't think any less of you.

Comment: As an aside, putting a comment below it (or replacing it with such a notice if it's longer, for best effect within the grace-period) that it was just an accidental double-post would be a courtesy to 10Ks.

Answer (score 14):

Just click the "delete" link.  No need to flag anyone.

Comment: I see what you did there! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Isn't flagging your post attracting a moderator's attention anyway? Just deleting the post is more than enough. It makes no sense to flag you own posts anyway, when you alone have the rights to delete it.