# What to do when a suggested edit adds a demo snippet?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, stack-snippets

What should we do when a suggested edit to an answer *adds* a working demo snippet? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7990706) is an example edit.

Intellectually, it adds nothing to the answer.

Plus, we can't go around [converting Fiddles to Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271589/suggested-edit-replacing-jsfiddle-with-stack-snippet-what-to-do) which would be similar, so I'm leaning toward discouraging this sort of behavior. Official answer?

Comment: Does it change the meaning of the answer, or does it just make it significantly better by adding a working demo? How would you feel if an accurate screenshot was added?

Comment: I though about if someone did that with one of my own answers. Since it's not a wiki answer, I'd prefer other people not expanding my answer, especially if it stands on it's own. I'm looking for an official answer from experienced Meta users.

Comment: I would reject the edit you've linked to. Seems like the suggested edit you've shown has got rejected.

Comment: Can you expand on why you don't want SO answer quality maximized? Should this user have posted the working snippet of your code as their own answer?

Comment: Well, intellectually they added nothing to the answer, and for the same reason we can't go around willy-nilly [converting Fiddles to Stack Snippets](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271589/suggested-edit-replacing-jsfiddle-with-stack-snippet-what-to-do), I'm leaning toward discouraging this sort of behavior.

Comment: That reference should be put it your question.

Answer (score 3):

Quotes from the [Stack Overflow Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

> With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.
>
> **Improve posts by editing or commenting**
>
> Our goal is to have the **best answers** to every question, so if you see questions or answers that can be improved, you can **edit** them.

I'd argue that the edit improves the quality of the post by having the code snippet in the answer.

Code snippets weren't available when the answer was originally posted (2012), so that would have been impossible to do at the time.

For reference, [the answer as posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074023/how-to-make-radius-only-in-top-border-in-css/10074095#10074095) without a demo:

---

> Brendan's answer is correct, but to get it to render in more browsers, you should use this:

```
-moz-border-radius: 0px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
```

---

Additions with the [demo included](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7990706):

> #### Working code snippet:
>
> ```css
> .borderRadiusTop30px {
>     -webkit-border-radius: 30px 30px 0px 0px;
>        -moz-border-radius: 30px 30px 0px 0px;
>             border-radius: 30px 30px 0px 0px;
> }
>
> div {
>     width: 240px;
>     height: 60px;
>     background: #44B449;
> }
> ```
>
> ```html
> <div></div>
> <br>
> <div class="borderRadiusTop30px"></div>
> ```

---

This snippet shows a live implementation of the code, and proves that it works.

The reject reason selected is misleading too:

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no
>   sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an
>   answer.

It's not a message to the author, it's intended to improve the quality of the answer.

The editors comment for the edit clarifies this:

> Comment: slightly modified example code and created working code snippet from it

With reference to the linked meta post:

[Suggested Edit Replacing JSFiddle with Stack Snippet, what to do?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271589/suggested-edit-replacing-jsfiddle-with-stack-snippet-what-to-do)

This is not mass editing and it's not swapping one thing for another, it's adding a demo where no demo exists, so it's a different scenario.

Comment: @AnnaLear here's another instance of the [duplicate answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265986/duplicate-answer) bug. I was editing around the expiration of the grace period I believe, not sure if that has any relevance to the problem. Whilst editing, I saw "a new answer has been posted" along the top. When I finished editing and saved, it was my own earlier version of the answer.

Comment: @AnnaLear as an aside, I think it was my second/maybe third edit within the grace period.