# Temporarily lost login while being active

Tags: support, login, logout, browser-support

It has happened to me a couple of times over the last few days that I was suddenly logged off while being active on StackOverflow. I then get a banner at the top of the browser window that offers me to log in again. The symptoms are very similar to what is described here:

[Constantly being kinda logged off](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262223/constantly-being-kinda-logged-off)

But I thought I would post a new question because my configuration is entirely different from the ones that were reported as affected there, and there wasn't really a clear conclusion anyway.

I'm seeing this with Internet Explorer 11.0.10 on Windows 8.1. I'm using my Google login credentials for SO, in case that matters. This only started happening recently, with no changes on my side that I'm aware of, except for possible automatic Windows updates.

Has anybody else seen this? Anything I can do to prevent it in the future?

While it has not been happening frequently, and is therefore not a huge deal, it is sort of inconvenient. When it just happened a few minutes ago, I was in the process of submitting an edit, and was at first completely puzzled that I got a message saying that it was submitted to the edit review queue.

Update: This just happened again. I finished typing an answer, and clicked the Submit button. Which did nothing. Tried a few more times, and only got a busy graphic for a moment, with no other action. Refreshed the page, and then it showed the banner at the top telling me that I had to log in again.

Comment: It happens to me all the time. It's annoying when happens while submitting a answer. Nothing happens, no error or indication that you're logged out. Then I when refresh and log back in, and resubmit the post it puts a Captcha up because it think you're a bot. Switching between Stack Exchange sites seems to make this happen more often.

Comment: What about the `Do-Not-Track` header?

Comment: This started happening to me as well over the last 2–3 days. My setup hasn't changed and I log in via FB. It happens on several SE sites (SO, codereview, PPCG), but independently (I get logged out of SO, but not PPCG; later it is PPCG, but not SO).

Comment: It hasn't happened to me nearly as much over the last 1-2 months. I think I got logged out once a couple of weeks ago. Around the time I posted this, it happened all the time.

Comment: FWIW, Firefox recently deleted all my cookies. Never saw that before!  No problems using Chrome.  I log in directly to SO, not with the OpenID or FB login.