# Random disconnections

Tags: bug, status-norepro, chat

More than once a day, Stack Overflow disconnects me. I may have not come back in an hour, or I may be chatting; I may have used another device to connect, or I may not; I suddenly will get errors about not being logged in when sending messages in the chat, or being simply disconnected on Stack Overflow.

I know I'm not [alone](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/20149905#20149905).

I use Chrome, but I've heard people having the same issue in Firefox. No one I know uses IE.

I hate reporting such a bug; non-reproducible bugs are the worst kind.

I'd say this happens since ~2-3 months or so.

Comment: These other people, are they sharing the same network?

Comment: @MartijnPieters well, we're all on the internet. But no, not the same local network at all.

Comment: I've experienced this too. I connect to chat on multiple devices, and this happens fairly often. Visiting the login page automatically logs me back in, but this seems new. I wasn't logged out nearly as often previously.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: sure, just eliminating obvious causes. :-) I haven't experienced this myself yet, if that's a datapoint.

Comment: I have experienced random disconnects but nowhere near once a day, in case that's useful

Comment: Oh, I'd like to clarify. It's not as frequent as once a day for me. Maybe twice a week.

Comment: I noticed it start right around the time the "kick-mute" function was added, but coincidentally miaou started being used by a lot of us regulars around the exact same time, for the exact same reason. I have no idea if they are connected. Just a thought.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com

Comment: I've also experienced this, across work, home, and cellular networks. I mainly notice it when I change devices/profiles, but I used to do that all the time and remain logged on. Now it feels like I'm logging into the sites several times a day.

Comment: Well, I can't say I've noticed such problems.  I use a distressingly large number of devices (iPad, iPhone, Android phone, 3 MacBook Pros, a Mac Mini and a Linux workstation — don't ask) and have hardly ever been logged out of SO; I don't remember when it last happened.  I do get logged out of the other sites, which I tend to visit less frequently, but that tends to be after multiple days of inactivity on the device.

Comment: have to tag this one as [tag:status-norepro]. we're excessively dogfooding meta/sites/chat to our SE teams (a lot of people are remote), and we'd surely notice such behavior very quickly.

Comment: so there are ghosts in my machines? Note: this happens not just on one machine or network for me. It happens equally at home and at work (albeit it only happens maybe 1-5 times a month)

Comment: @m0sa I can repro, and so can many other people ~ [tag:status-yesrepro]

Comment: @AwalGarg really? what are your steps to repo? I believe it ***is*** an issue, but as it stands it appears to be seemingly random. Until you've got steps to repo that go beyond "use the site for a month, it'll probably happen" it isn't reproducible.

Comment: @rlemon I don't have to do anything, it happens automatically. As a matter of fact, it happened this morning as well.

Comment: I guess repro is not the right word here then? correct me if I am wrong ;)

Comment: It's still an issue, but it isn't one we can reproduce at the drop of a dime. Generally when we say something is reproducible we have steps to achieve the results. This issue will be hard to test because we do not know the trigger. Should it be a concern? yes, I think it should. Can we reasonably reproduce it? no, no we cannot at this point in time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267977/temporarily-lost-login-while-being-active.

Comment: I experience the same problem with Safari on the iPhone, and it just happened again.

Comment: I get this only in StackOverflow with Safari on a single computer and after every 20min for sure.