# I keep getting logged out of Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-norepro, logout

I have multiple tabs open (Chrome version: Version 39.0.2171.71 (64-bit), Mac OS X 10.10.1).

If I close the Stack Overflow tab for any length of time (tested as low as 15 minutes), I get logged out when I try to open it up in a tab again.

This started yesterday.

When I click 'Log in', and start to click on 'Google', the site tells me I've been logged in and redirects me.

Comment: Why do I picture voting rings going *oh sh\*t* every time you reopen the Stack Overflow tab? Complete with cockroach-like scuttling into the shadows..

Comment: The whole login mechanism is cranky for long time and going through a  redesign: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243734/how-does-stack-exchange-lose-my-login#comment796753_243734

Comment: Get this on my phone too using Safari.

Comment: [status-norepo :P](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277917/random-disconnections)

Comment: Due to this misbehavior my "consecutive days counter" was incorrectly reset several times. Does stackoverflow give refunds?

Comment: Clean cookies related to stack*.com and try again.

Comment: @trylimits refunded back to a month :P

Comment: We are looking at how this can happen, just haven't found any holes yet. If anyone has other examples (including just reporting some timestamps when it happened so we can view more log data) it would be tremendously helpful.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's cranky, but it shouldn't be *this* cranky on any Q&A site.

Comment: @AnnaLear yup, that is true.

Comment: Solution: never close all your Stack Overflow tabs.

Comment: Only happens to me in StackOverflow. If you use the same code for your other sites then your login mechanism shouldn't be the main reason.

Comment: This is still an issue for me, I get logged out probably multiple times/week.

Comment: I usually have multiple SO tabs to fix the problem. And I can't reproduce it again.

Comment: Just started happening to me. I'm logged out several times a day. It started happening the same day when I subscribed to a RSS search. The feed refreshes about hourly.  Could that be it? However, I have an RSS search for unix.stackexchange.com also and that doesn't log me out.  I was even hit in the face with a Captcha.

Answer (score -3):

Are you getting logged out from Chrome only, and other browsers are OK?

Then you need to modify your `cookie` settings of Chrome:

*Settings* -> Show advanced settings -> *Privacy* -> Content settings -> *Cookie* and allow from there.

Comment: I've been getting logged out like this for the last year or so using the latest Safari/OS X. This only happens with StackOverflow and no other Exchange sites and is really annoying.